# Same constructor with different argument

Tags: android, constructor

As shown below, I have the following code as my constructor. But I want to duplicate it with different name. But I am getting error on this. Can I somehow modify to fit the requirement?

This is original code:

```
public HeyStatus(byte[] bytes)
    {
        this();

        int offset = 7;
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i)
        {
            partition1Status[i-1].status = (bytes[offset + i] & 0x0F);
            partition2Status[i-1].status = (bytes[offset + i + 9] & 0x0F);
        }

        if( (bytes[offset + 9] == 0) || (bytes[offset + 9] == 1)){
            isPartitioned = (bytes[offset + 9] == 0) ? false : true;
        }

        partition1Status.status = (bytes[offset + 18] - 0x30);
        partition2Status.status = (bytes[offset + 19] - 0x30);

        String model = "" + (char)bytes[1] + (char)bytes[2];
        if (model.equalsIgnoreCase("!A"))
            modelNum = "T32";
    }
```

I want to add this code after the previous code:

```
    public HeyStatus(byte[] bytes2)  <----the line I am getting error
    {
        this();

        int offset = 7;
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i)
        {
            partition3Status[i-1].status = (bytes[offset + i] & 0x0F);
            partition4Status[i-1].status = (bytes[offset + i + 9] & 0x0F);
        }


        if( (bytes[offset + 9] == 0) || (bytes[offset + 9] == 1)){
            isPartitioned = (bytes[offset + 9] == 0) ? false : true;
        }

        partition3Status.status = (bytes[offset + 18] - 0x30);
        partition4Status.status = (bytes[offset + 19] - 0x30);

        String model = "" + (char)bytes[1] + (char)bytes[2];
        if (model.equalsIgnoreCase("!A"))
            modelNum = "T32";
    }
```

Comment: I want exactly the same signature as you can see the code in both constructors are almost the same. It's about same variable which is not in same number.

Comment: Do you see it wrongly?my word is bear~

Comment: check the Edit of my answer it's the solution to your problem, if you don't understand i'll give more informations

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852252/same-constructor-with-different-argument/16853342#16853342), it's the best way to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) (constructors are special kind of methods).
In short you can only differenciate two methods by their name, and type of arguments.

> You cannot declare more than one method with the same name and the
>   same number and type of arguments, because the compiler cannot tell
>   them apart.

Answer (score 0):

```
public HeyStatus(byte[] bytes)
public HeyStatus(byte[] bytes2)
```

Both are same declaration. You need to change the type of parameter(`byte[]`) to overload the constructor. Constructor or Method overloading is based on difference in signatures. Here you are using the same signature for both the constructor definitions , just changing the parameter name, and this is invalid.

Read [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) for more.

*The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists*.

Answer (score 0):

You did not change the constructor signature. Both of constructors has same types:

```
public HeyStatus(byte[] bytes)
public HeyStatus(byte[] bytes2)
```

If you provides different types of arguments, different numbers of arguments, or both, you can define multiple constructors with the same name. It is calling [Constructor Overloaing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: But I want exactly the same signature as you can see the code in both constructors are almost the same. It's about same variable which is not in same number.

Comment: This is only definition. You can pass different arguments [in your code, different numbers] the constructor when calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two methods with the same signature in the same class. This also applies to constructors. There is no way for the compiler to know which one you're calling if you do something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = new bytes[]{1, 2, 3};
new HeyStatus(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use one constructor and when you call it put the appropriate bytes array within the parameters here is a simplified example:

```
byte[] bytesOne[]= new bytes[]{1,2,3};
byte[] bytesTwo[] =new bytes[]{4,5,6};

HeyStatus hStatusOne = new HeyStatus(bytesOne);
HeyStatus hStatusTwo = new HeyStatus(bytesTwo);
```

But only ONE contructor.

P.S. if you want to use more constructors parameters within it MUST be different from the first one, in type (not in name) and/or number. You can get more informations by googling overloading constructors.

Edit:

Just noticed the difference with partion1Status[] (and the others) put your partionStatus in the parameters.

example your constructors' head must look like this:

```
 public HeyStatus(byte[] bytes, typeOfpartionStatus partitionOneStatus, typeOfpartionStatus partitionTwoStatus){
this();

    int offset = 7;
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        partitionOneStatus[i-1].status = (bytes[offset + i] & 0x0F);
        partitionTwoStatus[i-1].status = (bytes[offset + i + 9] & 0x0F);
    }


    if( (bytes[offset + 9] == 0) || (bytes[offset + 9] == 1)){
        isPartitioned = (bytes[offset + 9] == 0) ? false : true;
    }

    partitionOneStatus.status = (bytes[offset + 18] - 0x30);
    partitionTwoStatus.status = (bytes[offset + 19] - 0x30);

    String model = "" + (char)bytes[1] + (char)bytes[2];
    if (model.equalsIgnoreCase("!A"))
        modelNum = "T32";
}
```

when you call it it must look like this.

```
HeyStatus hstatusOne = new (bytesOne,partion1Status,partition2Status);
HeyStatus hstatusTwo = new (bytesTwo,partion3Status,partition4Status);
```

Comment: Now i think i gave everything :)

Comment: I tried your solution, a lot of new errors associated with this code occurred. I am now debugging to see if it can be solved. If still persists, I would inform u. thank you for your kind help. Those who are just like to down voting, I don't understand what are they thinking about. They can just give the answer to me if they are able to help. Why down voting my question, as I said I am novice to android app development.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two constructors with the same paremeter count and types, you should use `static factory method` pattern. Make methods like 
`public static HeyStatus constructFromArray1(byte[] bytes) {...}`
 
and 
`public static HeyStatus constructFromArray2(byte[] bytes) {...}`
 
(you should name that methods properly, don't use the names that I proposed), that will construct objects properly, then you can construct objects from code like
`HeyStatus heyStatus = HeyStatus.constructFromArray1(bytes)`
 
(instead of `HeyStatus heyStatus = new HeyStatus(bytes)`.
 
It's the best way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one constructor by adding an extra (for example) int parameter to specify which of the code blocks to be executed. Like this, you'll have one constructor, containing the two blocks of code you need:

```
public HeyStatus(byte[] bytes, int option){
switch (option){
case 1: {
//you can place here the code you used in the first constructor
break;
}
case 2:{
//you can place here the code you used in the second constructor
break;
}
default: break;
}
```

And when you'll call the constructor, you will specify the option in the parameters list. 
Cheers!